# Calculating the minimum value of a certain column , and do simple data analysis

Tags: awk, multiple-columns, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I am new to awk and currently trying to perform some basic analysis on a simple text file. The file I am working with contains multiple fields (columns), and my goal is to accomplish the following:

- Identify the minimum value present in the third field (column).
- Divide each value in the third field (column) by the minimum value.
- Save the modified input file as a new file.

Here is the code that I have used:
 `awk 'NR == 1 { min = $3 } $3 < min { min = $3 } { print $1, $2, $3 / min }' input.txt > output.txt`

The first action in the code assigns the value in the third field of the first line to the variable "min". The third action is responsible for printing the values of the first, second, and third fields divided by the minimum value.

The first and second fields are printed correctly in the output file, but the third field, where the computations are made, appears to be incorrect. The numbers should vary because there is a single minimum value. What went wrong with my code?

Comment: for starters, change `$3 / min` to `$3 / ( min + ! min )` to guard against divide by zero error

Comment: You need a 2-pass approach, the first to calculate the min, and the second to apply the min. There's lots of examples on this forum, search the archives.